# should one protect internal docker services with reverse proxies and https+auth?

Tags: docker, security, devops, grafana, prometheus

Given services: `api`, `prometheus` (metrics monitoring), `grafana` (ui for metrics inspection).

`api` is accessible from outside (exposing a port) and it uses https as well as OAuth (both also for exposing metrics).

The monitoring services are deployed together using docker-compose and consist of:

`prometheus` does not expose any ports and is configured to be able to access the api-service to scrape the metrics. It is not explicitly secured with any authentication or encryption (besides the default docker-network encryption).

`grafana` exposes a web-facing port to be accessible from a devops team and hence is configured to use ssl and basic authentication. It uses the docker-internal network to query prometheus without any authentication.

---

I wonder if this setup has major drawbacks regarding security of the prometheus service? It is not secured at all, but not accessible from outside. Is it fine or should we still put a reverse proxy in front of it to add ssl and (basic) auth and let grafana use the proxy for communication rather than the docker-network?

I consider this question answered when there is a list of pro/con arguments and potential other relevant aspects not mentioned in the question or strong argumentation for either preferring internal docker communication or using reverse proxies.